# Odd behaviour on REST: Update/patch View doesn't allow get method and returns 405 when called via requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Similar questions have been asked before, but I can't seem to fix my problem with the answers.

I am trying to partially update an object and I overwrote the `partial_update method` in REST's generic `UpdateAPIView` but when I call this view via `requests` I get a `405:get method not allowed`-response.

What is extremely odd is that my code was working for about 2 weeks and now all of the sudden I get this error. I'm banging my head against a wall and can't seem to figure this out.

In my view I am doing this:

```
class BuildingUpdateAPI(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BuildingSerializer

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Patches building specified in URL with data in request."""

        network = Network.objects.get(name=self.kwargs["name_network"])
        building = network.buildings.get(name=self.kwargs["name_building"])

        serializer = BuildingSerializer(building, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(status=200, data=serializer.data)
        msg = (
            "Error message"
        )
        return JsonResponse(status=400, data=msg, safe=False)
```

My serializer is simple, it only defines the fields (but I can provide it if it helps).

In other answers it is said that REST looks for a `get-method` and can't find it. But I am calling this not via get, but via `patch`:

```
ep = "http://localhost:8000/path/to/update/"
data = {
   "update_field": "123"
}
r = requests.request("patch", url=ep, data=data, headers=get_headers())
```

Other answers say I am calling a wrong URL, but I am quite sure that it is the correct URL. And again, **this was working before and now it doesn't** . Or can I not call `Network.objects.get` within an update method? But that how could I do anything then...

And to make this thing even more ridiculous: I can update just fine using with REST-interface. But sending a patch-request via requests gives me that error (But I need to do that with requests)

I'm really out of options, any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance. If I can provide any more code or info just lmk.

Thanks.

Update: Also trying this via Postman gives the same error, so it's not a problem with requests I guess.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "api/v1/networks/<int:pk>/",
        NetworkDetailAPIById.as_view(),
        name="networks-detail-api-id",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/networks/<str:name>/",
        NetworkDetailAPIByName.as_view(),
        name="networks-detail-api-name",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/networks/update/<int:pk>/",
        NetworkUpdateAPI.as_view(),
        name="networks-update-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/networks/buildings/new/",
        NetworkBuildingCreateAPI.as_view(),
        name="networks-buildings-create-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/networks/project/<str:project_name>",
        NetworkProjectListAPI.as_view(),
        name="networks-project-list-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/buildings/<int:id>/",
        BuildingRetrieveAPI.as_view(),
        name="buildings-detail-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/buildings/delete/<int:id>",
        BuildingDeleteAPI.as_view(),
        name="buildings-delete-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/buildings/update/<str:name_network>/<str:name_building>",
        BuildingUpdateAPI.as_view(),
        name="buildings-update-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/network/buildings/<str:name_network>/",
        BuildingByNetworkListAPI.as_view(),
        name="network-buildings-list-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/time-series/",
        TimeSeriesAPI.as_view(),
        name="time-series-list-create-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/time-series/network/building/type-data/<str:name_network>/<str:name_building>/<str:type_data>/",
        TimeSeriesBuildingInNetworkAPI.as_view(),
        name="time-series-building-data-type-detail-api",
    ),
    path(
        "api/v1/time-series/project/type-data/step/<str:project>/"
        "<str:type_data>/<str:time_step>/",
        TimeStampBuildingsAPI.as_view(),
        name="timestamp-detail-api",
    ),

    path("api/v1/bldg/<str:name_network>/<str:name_building>/", SampleCreate.as_view(), name="sample")
]
```

Error when adding `get`:

```
500
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>AssertionError
          at /de/api/v1/bldg/TestDevNetworkBuilding4/Demand_1/</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }


..... plus a bunch of html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is missing the port component:

`ep = "http:localhost:/path/to/update/"`

should be something like:

`ep = "http:localhost:5000/path/to/update/"`

**UPDATE:**

Try adding a `patch` method to the class:

```
def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['partial'] = True
    return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then, change to :

```
r = requests.request("PATCH", url=ep, data=data, headers=get_headers())
```

or try:

```
r = requests.patch(url=ep, data=data, headers=get_headers())
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After troubleshooting:

That's an assertion error from `/de/api/v1/bldg/TestDevNetworkBuilding4/Demand_1` which matches your `SampleCreate.as_view()` URL pattern. The url is hitting the `path("api/v1/bldg/<str:name_network>/<str:name_building>/"` match.

Possible causes: you are confusing bldg and buildings in your url, or adding another url parameter, like language `de`, `en`, etc.

Comment: good catch, thanks but I just wrote that wrong here in the question.... It still throws me the error with the correct port component. Updated my question

Comment: I assume that's also the case for the missing `=` sign in `data {
   "update_field": "123"
}`

Comment: Yes :)  absolutely

Comment: I think we need to see your `urls.py` and the exact path used.  There may be a matching issue.

Comment: I'll happily share that. Problem is that I have quite a few and those are only the api-urls. I also thought that it might be a matching problem, so what I did was to create a sample-test view and moved the code there handling it with a test URL... same error... anyway sharing the URLS and updating the call. The relevant URL is named "buildings-update-api". The test URL is named "sample". I get the error with both

Comment: Try: `"^api/v1/buildings/update/<str:name_network>/<str:name_building>$",` and `"^api/v1/buildings/<int:id>/$",`, to make sure it isn't matching the shorter url.  Have you tried without the headers?

Comment: I changed both of the URLs as you suggested (is that a regex that validates for the longer URL?), unfortunately still the same error. Also I disabled authentication and sent it without the headers, without success... I also tried disabling all other URLs in the app, still the same... I'm clueless

Comment: Added the patch method. Still the same error unfortunately... Also before I had `partial_update` named `patch`. But both throw the same error

Comment: Also it's not a problem with the code. If I just add  `def patch(self):pass` and remove everything else I get the same error....

Comment: One last edit, forcing `partial` to `True`.  You must be going to the wrong url.  Can you check your network logs?  Can you `print()` first thing inside the class, like in a `get()` and/or `post` method?

Comment: Change `patch` to `PATCH`

Comment: Changing to `PATCH` still gives me the error. I added a get method like you suggested `def get(self, request, **kwargs):print(self.queryset)` which then throws me the error I added into my question (I hope this is what you meant)

Comment: could it be that the i18n language tags mess things up?

Comment: That's an assertion error from `/de/api/v1/bldg/TestDevNetworkBuilding4/Demand_1` which matches your `SampleCreate.as_view()` URL pattern.  Your url is not what you think it is.  You need to read the rest of the error message, but somewhere it `Assert False`.  More importantly, the url is hitting the `path("api/v1/bldg/<str:name_network>/<str:name_building>/"` match.  I think you are confused between `bldg` and `buildings` in your url.

Comment: My friend, you saved my day. You are right it was the wrong URL. I was hitting the URL with a `de` in front of it. If I add the language tag `en` to my API call it works... Can't believe it was such a small hidden thing.... Thank you so much for your time to troubleshoot this with me, really, really appreciated!!!

Comment: I'll accept your answer, if you want add a one liner for the reason of the assertion error. Thanks a bunch again!